# com.ibm.worklight.admin.common.util.exceptions.TimeoutException

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, maximo, maximo-anywhere

MobileFirst 6.3.0.00 Studio Plugin.  Working in development server for Maximo Anywhere.  Unable to deploy Adapter.

I am presented with "Adapter deployment failed: UndeclaredThrowableException" in the MobileFirstConsole.

I look at the MobielFirst Development Server and I see "CWWKX0204E: Unable to parse Throwable from server error stream".

Further down I see "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.worklight.admin.common.util.exceptions.TimeoutException"

I have rebuilt the MobielFirstServerConfigFolder multiple times at the direction of others and this does not seem to solve this particular problem.  I have searched my system and I in fact cannot locate this file.

Where should it be? and what is normal procedure for shoving it into its little home?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide the full server log and not bits from it.

Comment: Which log would you prefer?  The MobielFirst Development console output or the messages.log file? (of both?)  Should I attach it (how do I do that?) or just the whole of the text?  Thanks for your advice.

Comment: uploaded a few days ago and sent you an invite to look at them. have not heard anything.  please help.

Comment: Still waiting for you to provide something.

Comment: Sent items to you on several different fronts.  No help received.  Quite disappointed.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using the latest available v6.3 iFix will help.

As an IBM customer you can connect to IBM Fix Central, search for "mobilefirst platform", select 6.3 as your release version and download the latest available Studio fix.

Install it in fresh Eclipse that uses a new workspace and import your project into it. Start the server and deploy the adapter.

Comment: I am not a customer I am an IBMer.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am not getting files from you so I don't know what you disappointed from. You could have uploaded the files to google docs or Dropbox and share the link here and be done with with it, but you didn't. So you should be disappointed from yourself.